# MS Access 2003 prevent select all text on focus

Tags: ms-access-2003

MS Access 2003 has to be used, unfortunately.

I need to add a button to do some stuff on selected text in a Text control.  The problem is that I cannot get the `Text.SelStart`, or any other property unless it has focus.  When I do `Text.SetFocus`, all the text is automatically selected.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how 2003 works, but in Access 2010 go to File/Options/Client Settings/ under the Editing heading, Behavior entering field, select "Go to start of field" or "Go to end of field"...worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Access Setting, I don't know if you can change it programmatically. I only have german Access so I'll try to translate the menu to english:

go to `Tools` -> `Options` in the menu bar.

On the `Keyboard` tab, there is a box on the right `Behavior entering field`.

[image: Access Options Window]
<sub>(source: [flylib.com](http://flylib.com/books/2/401/1/html/2/FILES/06fig01.gif))</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately all options will also loose the current selection of the control.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is to bind the action to a key press event on the control.  Since the control does have focus, any operation can be done.

Also note that you should probably change the control **`Value`**, not **`Text`** property.